# How to compare and merge two files in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a Two text files ,names are one.txt and two.txt
In one.txt , contents are

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

In two.txt , contents are

```
DDD
EEE
```

I want a python code to determine a contains of two.txt are present in one.txt or not
If present means, don't do anything, But if contents of two.txt are not present means,it should append to one.txt

I want a output in one.txt as

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
EEE
```

Code:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r") 
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r") 
file3 = open("resultss.txt", "w") 
list1 = file1.readlines() 
list2 = file2.readlines() 
file3.write("here: \n") 
for i in list1: for j in list2: 
   if i==j: file3.write(i)
```

Comment: Please edit your code directly into the question.

Comment: Please add the code to your question and indent it by four spaces to preserve formatting; comments are not suitable for this, especially for a whitespace-dependent language like Python :)

Comment: Does the resultant file need to have any particular order? In your example, your two source files are sorted--is that to be assumed? May all three files be in memory at the same time (so the files are not very large)?

Comment: No need to in order format @ Rory Daulton

Answer (score 4):

that is simple with [sets](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), because it take care of the duplicates for you

**Edit**

```
with open('file1.txt',"a+") as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    new_words = set(file2) - set(file1)
    if new_words:
        file1.write('\n') #just in case, we don't want to mix to words together 
        for w in new_words:
            file1.write(w)
```

**Edit 2**

If the order is important go with Max Chretien answer.

If you want to know the common words, you can use intersection

```
with open('file1.txt',"a+") as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    words1 = set(file1)
    words2 = set(file2)
    new_words = words2 - words1
    common = words1.intersection(words2)
    if new_words:
        file1.write('\n')
        for w in new_words:
            file1.write(w)
    if common:
        print 'the commons words are'
        print common
    else:
        print 'there are no common words'
```

Comment: How about `set(file1) | set(file2)`?

Comment: Actually i want result in file1.txt itself , no need of output file @Copperfield

Comment: @stamaimer that work too, but I think that update don't create an intermediary throw away set

Comment: @Copperfield, new words value will provide a difference between the files,right? Just Curious-Is there any way to get the already presented words present in file2.txt..

Comment: @pavithranG yes, with intersection you get the words present in both files

Comment: answer upvoted because of the link into `set` documentation! (and the fact that you quoted me, I'm not gonna lie :p)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r+') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    f1 = [i.strip() for i in file1.readlines()]
    f2 = [j.strip() for j in file2.readlines()]
    f1 += [item for item in f2 if item not in f1]
    file1.seek(0)
    for line in f1:
        file1.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar solution using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) maybe a bit shorter...

```
with open('one.txt', 'r+') as f_one, open('two.txt', 'r') as f_two:
    res = sorted(set(f_one) | set(f_two))
    f_one.seek(0)
    f_one.writelines(res)
```