# How to glue (stitch) two python code together?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering what is the best way to put together codes from different python files into a new python file.
Lets say the first file `1.py`would consist of:

```py
def(...):
    a=1
    b=2
    return c=a+b
```

And another file `2.py` consists of:

```py
def(...):
    d = 4
    e = c*d
    return e
```

Now let's say you have a final file, `final.py`, which you want all the codes from `1.py` and `2.py` copied word by word to it in a specific order of operation where it looks as below. Note that I understand we can use the import function in python but in this case, I would like the whole text of certain definitions to be copied to the new python code. In another term, glue the codes from different files to build a new file.

final.py:

```py
def(...):
    a=1
    b=2
    return c=a+b
def(...):
    d = 4
    e = c*d
    return e
```

**EDIT:**

Rephrase above: what if file 1 has 100 definitions and file 2 has 100 definitions but I want specific ones from each file copied over to file 3 with full text and syntax in a specified order.

Comment: `ctr+c` -> `ctrl+v` ?

Comment: A solution is to use also a python program for that, as can be see in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871417/how-to-compare-and-merge-two-files-in-python

Comment: Instead of creating a new module, you could just `import` the functions you want using for example `from 1.py import func_a, func_d, etc` and the do something similar for `2.py`.

Comment: Even with the edit, it still isn't hard. Python is very indentation-dependent, meaning, you just search for the def you need, then you copy every line until the indentation ends.

Comment: But I agree with @martineau, it's unclear what you are actually trying to accomplish with this, but I sense that there are easier ways than merging source files.

Comment: what @martineau suggested would work but not in this case. I'm working on a program of programs which I was exploring how to develop a program from a set of distributed codes and wanted certain definitions to be inserted in a predefined order of operation from various files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that in python itself!

Assuming you have a list of requiered definitions:

```py
import re

files = ["1.py", "2.py"]  # ......
defs = ["func_1", "func_2"]

with open("final.py", 'w') as out_f:
    for path in files:
        with open(path) as in_f:
            lines = in_f.readlines()
            i = 0
            while i < len(lines):
                line = lines[i]
                r = re.search("^def\s+(\w+)\(", line)
                if r:
                    if r.group(1) in defs:
                        out_f.write(line)
                        while i < len(lines) and not re.search("^\w", lines[i+1]): # relying on python's indent syntax
                            out_f.write(lines[i+1])
                            i += 1
                i += 1
```

Comment: Your method would have worked if every line was needed. Only elements of each file are needed per se.

Comment: Skip empty lines or entire def. Search a file full of definitions and find a specific definition and copy it. Also, this could be done for multiple definitions and files as well.

Comment: You could add a list of requiered definitions and filter. How many are there?

Comment: It could be any number. I need it to be generic to handle any quantity of definitions and file to search.

Comment: So you're looking for a function that: identifies a definition, checks the name against a list of desired definitions, and based on that result either ingests the definition or "i++'s" and moves on?

Comment: @Kevin_ALA I have added to my code. Is this what you meant?

Comment: That is the closest thing to what I was imagining. Thanks a lot @Tomerikoo.

Comment: @Kevin_ALA please note I have added an important condition to the second loop in case one of the definitions you need is last in file!

Comment: @Tomerikoo you also have to check for empty lines, empty lines don't start with whitespace but don't end a function

Comment: I was thinking about the option that a function can have an empty line inside it. Meaning I can't stop on empty line because the next might still be part of the function. If you have a specific known structure which this don't happen, you can alter the conditions

Comment: Also, a comment can be at the start of a line without whitespace, still doesn't end the function

Comment: So I suppose to handle the blank lines/end of the definition, the read could be set to, once the initial desired definition is found, to continue reading until it comes across another def()?

Comment: Yeah I was going for something even more general assuming there might be any line of code. But counting on that any other code of the same indent level means the end of definition

Comment: @Finomnis a comment will not end the function in my code also. `#` is not included in the `\w` group of regex

Comment: @Tomerikoo you are correct. My bad. Still, it's an incorrect assumption that all code lines start with `\w`. example: `(a,b) = function()` would **not** end your function, while it definitely is a code line. The correct way, imo, is to separately check for whether it is a code line, by checking if it doesn't start with `\s*#` or only contains `\s*`. Then you need to see if the line starts with the same indentation, not just any indentation.

Answer (score 6):

If you're on a unix shell:

`cat 1.py 2.py > 3.py`

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem in your OS tools, not Python.  You're simply concatenating two text files.  You can look up how to do that in your OS.  If you have a favorite text editor, open a new file.  Read in `1.py`; at the bottom of that, read in `2.py`; save the result as `3.py`.

Answer (score 1):

This got a little out of hand, but I tried to re-implement it with proper structure, and this is what I came up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re

def extract_functions(code_lines, names):

    # Checks if given line contains code
    def is_code_line(line):
        stripped = line.strip()
        if stripped.startswith('#'):
            return False
        if len(stripped) == 0:
            return False
        return True

    # Retreives the indentation pattern of given line
    def get_indentation(line):
        num_indent_chars = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        return line[:num_indent_chars]

    # Returns the function name if line has a function definition, else None
    function_name_extractor = re.compile(r'^def\s+(\w+)\s*\(')
    def get_function_name(line):
        match = function_name_extractor.match(line)
        if match is None:
            return None
        return match.group(1)

    extracted = list()
    in_function = False 

    for num, line in enumerate(code_lines):
        # Non-code lines don't end or start functions,
        # even if their indentation is wrong
        if not is_code_line(line):
            continue

        if in_function:
            # If this is the first line of the function, store the indentation
            if function_indent == None:
                function_indent = get_indentation(line)

            # If we match the indentation, we are still in the same function.
            # Store that the function includes the current line
            if line.startswith(function_indent):
                function_end = num + 1

            # If we detect the end of the current function, extract the
            # function lines and store them in 'extracted'.
            else:
                extracted.extend(code_lines[function_start:function_end])
                in_function = False

        # If we are currently not inside a function, check if current line
        # contains a function start.
        # Needs a separate 'if' and not just an 'else' because this code
        # needs to run if the previous 'if' detected the end of a function.
        if not in_function:
            line_function_name = get_function_name(line)
            if line_function_name is not None and line_function_name in names:
                in_function = True
                function_start = num
                function_end = num + 1
                function_indent = None

    # One more extraction if the function reaches all the way to the last line
    if in_function:
        extracted.extend(code_lines[function_start:function_end])

    return extracted




with open('1_and_2.py', 'w') as out_fil:
    with open('1.py', 'r') as fil:
        for line in extract_functions(fil.readlines(), ['func_a1', 'func_b1']):
            out_fil.write(line) 
        # It isn't guaranteed that our last line in the file ends with a newline,
        # Therefore add one manually
        out_fil.write('\n')
    with open('2.py', 'r') as fil:
        for line in extract_functions(fil.readlines(), ['func_a2', 'func_b2']):
            out_fil.write(line) 
        out_fil.write('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test it and will get back to you

Comment: Merged it to one function and added a couple of comments. Also, please remove the accepted flag from the other solution until it can handle all special cases.